# error 404 en Select2 al migrar mi proyecto a linux desde windows

Tags: select2

Emigre de windows a linux manajaro y el proyecto django en el que estoy trabajando no reconoce o encuentra el camino del select2 en los static pero si encuentra el resto de los ficheros static. Es necesario reinstalar la biblioteca para linux?

esta es mi configuracion en setting:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```